# Eclipse Background

Tags: android, eclipse

I've just recently started coding with Eclipse so I don't know a whole lot about it. I was wondering, how do you change the background of and activity and also the color/pattern of buttons in Eclipse while working on an Android Application.

Thank You

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually all this stuff should be accessed from xml editor. If you have some difficulties, just open the xml representation of layout and feel free to modify it the most common way(editor independent). The switch between the xml text and designer should be in the end of editor.

Also you should look for properties window on the right side of your editor if you want to edit design properties from UI representation of layout

Answer (score 0):

In res>layout>xml, android:background="#000000" or any color you want inside " "